# PHP and MAMP - send and read headers

Tags: php, mamp

I have set a `mamp` server on a Mac, and i am sending a request using Safari:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

Which works, where the `index.php` file is this :

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Question, how would i **send** and **receive** some fields together with the address so:

```
http://localhost:8888/name=me&&city=somecity
```

then, having some basic PHP code to read each and every field (name/city etc.)?

when i am adding `/name=me&&city=somecity` to the address I get error.

Comment: The `key=value` part is typically a query string, starting with a `?`. Else you'd need a RewriteRule or FallBackResource to capture the REQUEST_PATH and extract it afterwards.

Comment: ok, so if using the "?" , is there a simple way to add fields and read them?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Information that you got an error has no value. The most important information is the error message.

Comment: thanks, i have tried that with http://localhost:8888?name=me , but then i am redirected from the browser to google... do i have to add the index.php at the end ?

Comment: @Curnelious The link is supposed to be like: `http://localhost:8888/?name=me`

Comment: thanks a lot ! you helped me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it with :

```
http://localhost:8888/index.php?name=me
```

and code: (took for the link provided to me by @hjpotter92)

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
?>
```